# Numbered page-navigation of Google Blogger not working on search results page

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I have added a numbered page-navigation script on my Blogger and it is working fine with all pages except the search results page *(the page shown with results when I make a search for posts)* -- it is showing default "previous post and newer posts" on that page.

Actually I didn't know too much about JavaScript therefore I need help to modify the given JavaScript so that it works also on search result page as like Wordpress.

I am happy to supply any additional needed details.

Thanks in advance... :-)

```js
 /*<![CDATA[*/
    var perPage=7;
    var numPages=6;
    var firstText ='First';
    var lastText ='Last';
    var prevText ='« Previous';
    var nextText ='Next »';
    var urlactivepage=location.href;
    var home_page="/";
  /*]]>*/

  /*<![CDATA[*/
    if (typeof firstText == "undefined") firstText = "First"; 
    if (typeof lastText == "undefined") lastText = "Last";
    var noPage;
    var currentPage;
    var currentPageNo;
    var postLabel;
    pagecurrentg();

    function looppagecurrentg(pageInfo) {
        var html = '';
        pageNumber = parseInt(numPages / 2);
        if (pageNumber == numPages - pageNumber) {
            numPages = pageNumber * 2 + 1
        }
        pageStart = currentPageNo - pageNumber;
        if (pageStart < 1) pageStart = 1;
        lastPageNo = parseInt(pageInfo / perPage) + 1;
        if (lastPageNo - 1 == pageInfo / perPage) lastPageNo = lastPageNo - 1;
        pageEnd = pageStart + numPages - 1;
        if (pageEnd > lastPageNo) pageEnd = lastPageNo;
        html += "<span class='showpageOf'>Page " + currentPageNo + ' of ' + lastPageNo + "</span>";
        var prevNumber = parseInt(currentPageNo) - 1;
      
  //Iccsi was here, doing magic      
        if (currentPageNo > 1) {
   if (currentPage == "page") {
     html += '<span class="showpage firstpage"><a href="' + home_page + '">' + firstText + '</a></span>'
   } else {
     html += '<span class="displaypageNum firstpage"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">' + firstText + '</a></span>'
   }
  }
  
  if (currentPageNo > 2) {
            if (currentPageNo == 3) { 
                if (currentPage == "page") {
                    html += '<span class="showpage"><a href="' + home_page + '">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
                } else {
                    html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
                }
            } else {
                if (currentPage == "page") {
                    html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + prevNumber + ');return false">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
                } else {
                    html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + prevNumber + ');return false">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
                }
            }
        }
        if (pageStart > 1) {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="' + home_page + '">1</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">1</a></span>'
            }
        }
        if (pageStart > 2) {
            html += ' ... '
        }
        for (var jj = pageStart; jj <= pageEnd; jj++) {
            if (currentPageNo == jj) {
                html += '<span class="pagecurrent">' + jj + '</span>'
            } else if (jj == 1) {
                if (currentPage == "page") {
                    html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="' + home_page + '">1</a></span>'
                } else {
                    html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">1</a></span>'
                }
            } else {
                if (currentPage == "page") {
                    html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + jj + ');return false">' + jj + '</a></span>'
                } else {
                    html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + jj + ');return false">' + jj + '</a></span>'
                }
            }
        }
        if (pageEnd < lastPageNo - 1) {
            html += '...'
        }
        if (pageEnd < lastPageNo) {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastPageNo + '</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastPageNo + '</a></span>'
            }
        }


        var nextnumber = parseInt(currentPageNo) + 1;
        if (currentPageNo < (lastPageNo - 1)) {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + nextnumber + ');return false">' + nextText + '</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + nextnumber + ');return false">' + nextText + '</a></span>'
            }
  }
  
  if (currentPageNo < lastPageNo) {
   //Iccsi was here, doing magic
   if (currentPage == "page") {
     html += '<span class="displaypageNum lastpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastText + '</a></span>'
   } else {
     html += '<span class="displaypageNum lastpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastText + '</a></span>'
   }
        }

        var pageArea = document.getElementsByName("pageArea");
        var blogPager = document.getElementById("blog-pager");
        for (var p = 0; p < pageArea.length; p++) {
            pageArea[p].innerHTML = html
        }
        if (pageArea && pageArea.length > 0) {
            html = ''
        }
        if (blogPager) {
            blogPager.innerHTML = html
        }
    }

    function totalcountdata(root) {
        var feed = root.feed;
        var totaldata = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t, 10);
        looppagecurrentg(totaldata)
    }

    function pagecurrentg() {
        var thisUrl = urlactivepage;
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1) {
            if (thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max") != -1) {
                postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max"))
            } else {
                postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?&max"))
            }
        }
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("?q=") == -1 && thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1) {
            if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") == -1) {
                currentPage = "page";
                if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                    currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
                } else {
                    currentPageNo = 1
                }
                document.write("<script src=\"" + home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata\"><\/script>")
            } else {
                currentPage = "label";
                if (thisUrl.indexOf("&max-results=") == -1) {
                    perPage = 20
                }
                if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                    currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
                } else {
                    currentPageNo = 1
                }
                document.write('<script src="' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary/-/' + postLabel + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata&max-results=1" ><\/script>')
            }
        }
    }

    function redirectpage(numberpage) {
        jsonstart = (numberpage - 1) * perPage;
        noPage = numberpage;
        var nameBody = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var newInclude = document.createElement('script');
        newInclude.type = 'text/javascript';
        newInclude.setAttribute("src", home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?start-index=" + jsonstart + "&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=finddatepost");
        nameBody.appendChild(newInclude)
    }

    function redirectlabel(numberpage) {
        jsonstart = (numberpage - 1) * perPage;
        noPage = numberpage;
        var nameBody = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var newInclude = document.createElement('script');
        newInclude.type = 'text/javascript';
        newInclude.setAttribute("src", home_page + "feeds/posts/summary/-/" + postLabel + "?start-index=" + jsonstart + "&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=finddatepost");
        nameBody.appendChild(newInclude)
    }

    function finddatepost(root) {
        post = root.feed.entry[0];
        var timestamp1 = post.published.$t.substring(0, 19) + post.published.$t.substring(23, 29);
        var timestamp = encodeURIComponent(timestamp1);
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            var pAddress = "/search?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
        } else {
            var pAddress = "/search/label/" + postLabel + "?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
        }
        location.href = pAddress
    }
  /*]]>*/
```

```css
#blog-pager{clear:both;margin:30px auto;text-align:center; padding: 7px; }
.blog-pager {background: none;}
.displaypageNum a,.showpage a,.pagecurrent{font-size: 13px;padding: 5px 12px;margin-right:5px; color: #AD0B00; background-color:#FAB001;}
.displaypageNum a:hover,.showpage a:hover, .pagecurrent{background:#DB4920;text-decoration:none;color: #fff;}
#blog-pager .pagecurrent{font-weight:bold;color: #fff;background:#DB4920;}
 .showpageOf{display:none!important}
#blog-pager .pages{border:none;}
```

Comment: Anyone, please answer

Comment: Could you share a demo blog on which you have implemented this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you will have to modify the search box, Changing the form action attribute from

```
action="/search/max-results=12"
```

to

```
action="/search/"
```

Specifiy the `max-results` parameter as a hidden `input` field

```
<input type='hidden' name='max-results' value="12" />
```

Secondly in the JavaScript code above, search for the following line -

```
if (thisUrl.indexOf("?q=") == -1 && thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1)
```

and replace it with -

```
if (thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1)
```

The above condition (aka `thisUrl.indexOf("?q=") == -1`) was stopping the script to work on pages with a query parameter named `q` in the URL

#### Edit 1: For showing correct Page Numbers on Search results pages

Search for the following function in the above code -

```
function redirectpage(numberpage) {
    jsonstart = (numberpage - 1) * perPage;
    noPage = numberpage;
    var nameBody = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var newInclude = document.createElement('script');
    newInclude.type = 'text/javascript';
    newInclude.setAttribute("src", home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?start-index=" + jsonstart + "&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=finddatepost");
    nameBody.appendChild(newInclude)
}
```

Replace it with -

```
function redirectpage(numberpage) {
    jsonstart = (numberpage - 1) * perPage;
    noPage = numberpage;
    var nameBody = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var newInclude = document.createElement('script');
    newInclude.type = 'text/javascript';
    if(urlactivepage.indexOf("?q=") == -1){
        newInclude.setAttribute("src", home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?start-index=" + jsonstart + "&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=finddatepost");
    } else {
        newInclude.setAttribute("src", home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?start-index=" + jsonstart + "&alt=json-in-script&q="+ urlactivepage.split("?")[1].split("q=")[1].split("&")[0] +"&callback=finddatepost");  
    }
    nameBody.appendChild(newInclude);
}
```

Then search for the following block of code -

```
function pagecurrentg() {
    var thisUrl = urlactivepage;
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1) {
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max") != -1) {
            postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max"))
        } else {
            postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?&max"))
        }
    }
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("?q=") == -1 && thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1) {
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") == -1) {
            currentPage = "page";
            if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            document.write("<script src=\"" + home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata\"><\/script>")
        } else {
            currentPage = "label";
            if (thisUrl.indexOf("&max-results=") == -1) {
                perPage = 20
            }
            if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            document.write('<script src="' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary/-/' + postLabel + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata&max-results=1" ><\/script>')
        }
    }
}
```

and replace it with -

```
function pagecurrentg() {
    var thisUrl = urlactivepage;
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1) {
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max") != -1) {
            postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max"))
        } else {
            postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?&max"))
        }
    }
    if (thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1) {
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") == -1) {
            currentPage = "page";
            if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            if(thisUrl.indexOf("q=") == -1){
                document.write("<script src=\"" + home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata\"><\/script>")
            } else {
                document.write("<script src=\"" + home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?q=" + thisUrl.split("?")[1].split("q=")[1].split("&")[0] + "&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata\"><\/script>")
            }
       } else {
            currentPage = "label";
            if (thisUrl.indexOf("&max-results=") == -1) {
                perPage = 20
            }
            if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            document.write('<script src="' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary/-/' + postLabel + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata&max-results=1" ><\/script>')
        }
    }
}
```

Then search for the following block of code

```
function finddatepost(root) {
    post = root.feed.entry[0];
    var timestamp1 = post.published.$t.substring(0, 19) + post.published.$t.substring(23, 29);
    var timestamp = encodeURIComponent(timestamp1);
    if (currentPage == "page") {
        var pAddress = "/search?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
    } else {
        var pAddress = "/search/label/" + postLabel + "?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
    }
    location.href = pAddress
}
```

and replace it with -

```
function finddatepost(root) {
    post = root.feed.entry[0];
    var timestamp1 = post.published.$t.substring(0, 19) + post.published.$t.substring(23, 29);
    var timestamp = encodeURIComponent(timestamp1);
    if (currentPage == "page") {
        if(urlactivepage.indexOf("?q=") == -1){
                var pAddress = "/search?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
        } else {
                var pAddress = "/search?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&q="+ urlactivepage.split("?")[1].split("q=")[1].split("&")[0] +"&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
            }
        } else {
        var pAddress = "/search/label/" + postLabel + "?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
    }
    location.href = pAddress
}
```

In all these blocks of code, I have added extra conditions to handle the  query parameter conditon. In case you are getting confused, then the new files as a whole looks like - [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StylifyYourBlog/stylifyyourblog.github.io/42299d75a81e69ce157ac70269b70d8ed7b6afb4/test.js) . An working example can be checked here - https://prayagverma.blogspot.com/?q=Tweet .

**Note:** Also I had remove the `max-results` from the JSON API calls above as they were affecting the `openSearch$totalResults.$t` parameter (which it normally shouldn't)

Comment: Awsome brother ! Thanks 999999 times

Comment: Another problem, eg when i make a search their are two results but page navigation show five pages and if i click on and number say 2 it shows unrelevant result according to query.

Comment: I have made max result for search form and page navigation to 1. Please check this out

Comment: Change the value of `postperpage` variable to match with the value of `max-results`. As we set the `max-results` to 12 in the hidden input field, make sure that `postperpage` has the same value. Also one more thing, make sure that `postperpage` matches with the post per page set in the Blogger dashboard (In Layout > Blog Posts gadget). All these values should be same to avoid any post from being skipped when going from one page to another.

Comment: Already done , the problem is if i made any search say 'style' normally this show two result but after change limit to say 1 for both search and pagenav it show 1 result correct and when i click to see second result it show something else and also show result in 3 number. May be he was taking wrong script for search page and i think first result correct and after that the result are of home page

Comment: In short after clicking on numbers it is showing wrong result and shows all of my post like home page

Comment: @Bloggerz updated the answer with other changes that need to be done to make it function correctly

Comment: Hi Prayag, I have another problem in my imageLightbox script. I think you can solve it pls visit here http://stackoverflow.com/q/35731002/5941485

Comment: @Bloggerz If you found this answer useful, do mark it as a solution. Thanks