# How to add more than one selector in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

How can i add more the one variable in JavaScript :

```
var selector = 'a[href$=png]:has(img)';
```

So that it can get images with other format like jpg, jpeg and bmp also.

Full script https://googledrive.com/host/0Bx94NfJgN888WWVnNTk5UHhhbk0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple selectors in the same statement to select anything that matches either of your selectors, like so:

```
$('.selector1, .selector2')
```

This will match any element with the class selector1 **or** selector2. Therefore you could try something like the following:

```
var selector = 'a[href$=png],a[href$=jpg]';
$(selector)...
```

Comment: Actually its is imagelightbox . Its working great but now the // arrows were not working properly they are show same image again and again but navigation button working fine